# How smart is Java about if statements with final variables

Tags: java, debugging, if-statement, final

I'd like to write some troubleshooting code which i can easily remove from later non debug versions of my program. I came up with:

```
final static boolean debug_on=true;
...
if (debug_on) { system.out.println() or logger.log(...) }
```

Is Java smart enough to drop the if statement from the final bytecode if debug==false ?

Is there a better practice to achieve the goal of keeping debug code out of the final version of a program ?

Comment: did you check the byte code ?

Comment: This looks like it should be easy to test - compile, and then use javap to see the bytecode. (I'd expect it to be optimized by the JIT, not javac)

Comment: Is it really worth optimizing this (the test) by using a final variable? Usually, one uses a logging framework, and then writes statements like `if (log.isDebugEnabled()) log.debug("blah "+x);`. The test is performed every time but `"blah"+x`is not evaluated.

Comment: Problem with log.isDebugEnabled() for me is that it will have to be evaluated every time. Having the answer to my question i prefer the compiler to strike out any such code if it is clear that i want no debug information of that granularity.

Comment: I checked the respective files and found evidence that it is indeed cut from the byte code when debug_on==false. Thank you for the suggestion, i never used javap before. Will come in handy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the end of the [Java language specification chapter 14.21. Unreachable Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21)  for a description of `if(false)`:

> ```
> if (false) { x=3; }
> ```
>
> does not result in a compile-time error. An optimizing compiler may
>   realize that the statement `x=3;` will never be executed and may choose
>   to omit the code for that statement from the generated class file, but
>   the statement `x=3;` is not regarded as "unreachable" in the technical
>   sense specified here.
>
> The rationale for this differing treatment is to allow programmers to
>   define "flag variables" such as:
>
> ```
> static final boolean DEBUG = false;
> ```
>
> and then write code such as:
>
> ```
> if (DEBUG) { x=3; }
> ```
>
> The idea is that it should be possible to change the value of DEBUG
>   from false to true or from true to false and then compile the code
>   correctly with no other changes to the program text.

**tl;dr;** It depends on the compiler whether the statements inside your if are omitted in the bytecode.

Comment: Unreachable statements ! Did not think to look it up by that name. Thank you !